# How do I restrict project creation in Phabricator

Tags: phabricator

Is there a way in Phabricator to restrict which users can create a new project?

I have looke everywhere but cannot find the policy that will restrict this feature to select users.

Answer (score 1):

- Logon to Phabricator as administrator
- Go to [1]: https://phabricator-URL/applications/view/PhabricatorProjectApplication/

The you should see this and config the policies:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1crpW.png

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I did not look hard enough.

This is possible by setting an entry in policy.locked through the command line:

```
./bin/config set policy.locked "{ \"project.create\" : \"admin\" }"
```